# Water damage on a macbook air 2020

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, repair, damage

I’m really stressed right now so I might write some nonsense. I just spilled some water on my macbook air 2020 M1. It wasn’t that much in my opinion but clearly more than a few drops. I didn’t shut it right away because I panicked but I made sure to lift the computer in a way that the water would fall out and then gently cleaned the rest with a cloth. After that i didn’t think on checking what i had to do online and started making some test to see if everything works. My keyboard is fully functional and so is my touchpad,as i thought,but it started making some weird noise. I cleaned again the edges and then finally shut it down. The speakers work and also the screen. No glitches and no shutdowns. I’m really scared that by my initial response the water made it’s way into the main system proof being the touch pad noise. If someone knows more about the effects of water damage please tell me if it’s possible that my macbook is already broken and what should i do to fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately, you did the exact wrong things.  However, **this is still salvagable if you take it into a qualified repair shop**.  Stop using it until you can get things cleaned.